# trying to understand -Wsign-conversion error

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following sample program, which gives me an error:

`error: conversion to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >::difference_type {aka long int}’ from ‘std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]
     for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.begin() + pos; ++iter) {
                                                     ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors`

if I compile it with `-Wsign-conversion`, i.e.:
`g++ ./test.cpp  -std=c++11 -Wsign-conversion`

source:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 

int main() {
    std::vector<std::size_t> v;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    std::size_t pos = 4;

    for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.begin() + pos; ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain why it is an error, and how should I go about dealing with it? Thank you.

**update**:
What if I have the following scenario:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 

static bool someCondition(std::size_t i) {
    return true; //just in case
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::size_t> v;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        v.push_back(i);
    } 

    // I have some initial counter value
    std::size_t candidatesIndex = 0;

    // later I refill the vector somehow if some condition is true for the particular vector's index
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {

        if (someCondition(i)) {

            if (candidatesIndex >= v.size()) {
                v.push_back(i);
            } else {
                v[candidatesIndex] = i; 
            }

            ++candidatesIndex;  
        }
    }

    //now the vector contains 20 items, but I am interested only in the first 5 ones
    //and my candidatesIndex gives me that information (i.e. it equals to 5, not 20)
    std::cout << candidatesIndex << " " << v.size() << std::endl; // 5 20

    //now I want to iterate through the first 5 calculated values (where 5 is my candidatesIndex) 
    //and perform some logic    
    for (auto iter = v.begin(); iter != v.begin() + candidatesIndex; ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

how should I declare my `candidatesIndex` to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: Make `pos` a `ptrdiff_t` (or, to be pedantic, `std::vector<std::size_t>::difference_type`), rather than `size_t`. `iterator::operator+` expects a signed integer for an offset - it's OK for iterators to move backward.

Comment: one more question, how can I correctly compare `std::vector<std::size_t>::difference_type` value with `v.size()` (where `v` is my vector above)?

Comment: Why would you want to? What's the goal of such a comparison?

Comment: You could cast: `iter != v.begin() + static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(candidatesIndex)`